# OpenSSH for Windows over HTTP proxy

Tags: windows, openssh, http-proxy

I have a standard setup:

> Client (Windows 2019) -->  HTTP Proxy --> SSH Server (Ubuntu) -->
>   Server

I want to port forward my local port to the server.

I am able to connect successfully from the client, using this setup to the Server. I have not specified anything related to the proxy in my call

```
ssh -v -p 22 -N -C -L 50000:WinServer:8080 user@SSHServer
```

I think this means, that the OpenSSH implementation is picking up the default proxy setting from the client system. I want to explicitly specify the proxy, so I can isolate my solution from the client machine setup.

I tried the ProxyCommand option as follows:

```
PS C:\scripts> ssh.exe -vvv -C -L 50000:WinServer:8080 -o ProxyCommand="ssh.exe -v -W %h:%p -p proxy-port proxy-host" user@SSHServer

OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh.exe -v -W SSHServer:22 -p proxy-port proxy-host
debug3: spawning "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe" -v -W SSHServer:22 -p proxy-port proxy-host
debug3: w32_getpeername ERROR: not sock :2
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5  

debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug1: Connecting to proxy-host [proxy-host] port proxy-port.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2  

debug1: Connection established.  

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7  

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

My constraints:

1. I cannot change anything on the proxy. Indeed my solution will be
   deployed in various customers so I should not assume anything other
   than an HTTP proxy.
2. I have limited capability to add/change software
   on the client. I would like to use the default Microsoft feature if
   possible. Any third party software would need to be qualified, and
   that is a pain.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Before we can help you will need to fix the permissions issues on your SSH key and resolve the OpenSSH configuration warnings.  Those warnings, as it stands, indicate you have a configuration error that must be resolved (and are likely the reason your unable to do what you want).  The SSH keys must have specific permissions, the OpenSSH documentation, is very specific on what those permissions must be.

Comment: **Yes;**  In order to solve your problem, configuration changes to the client, must be performed.  You could also disable key authentication and only allow password authentication but that required a server configuration change. Does `C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/config` or `C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config` event exist on your system?